# MySql/MariaDB cannot change default datadir on Debian 9.1 server

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb

I have a problem to move the default datadir of Maria DB to another partition, it appears to be very common but i tried everything I can without luck.

Mysql is installed as Mariadb 10.1.26 with the default debian package (`apt-get install mysql-server`) on a Debian 9.1 (stretch) server, `mysqld -v` returns `mysqld 10.1.26-MariaDB-0+deb9u1`

Default_mysql_datadir : `/var/lib/mysql`

New_mysql_datadir : `/home/mysql`

`/var/lib/mysql` is mounted to "`/`" (`/dev/md3`)

`/home/mysql` is mounted to "`/home`" (`/dev/md4`)

What I've tried

```
# systemctl stop mysql
# mv /var/lib/mysql /home
```

Change datadir in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
# datadir = /home/mysql
```

Check if the rights/permissions are ok

`# chown -R mysql.mysql /home/mysql`

**apparmor is NOT installed** nor running on the system though the `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` file is existing with the following rules :

```
/home/mysql/ r,
/home/mysql/** rwk,
```

I even tried to create and empty `/var/lib/mysq` folder refering to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1574782)

But when I start I always get the same error :

```
# systemctl start mysql
[Warning] Can't create test file /home/mysql/<user>.lower-test
#007/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't change dir to '/home/mysql/' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied") 2017-09-07  0:16:59 140119808397888 [ERROR] Aborting
mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Failed to start MariaDB database server.
mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Any suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: question should be on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks Raymond, you are right, I moved it to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185302/mysql-mariadb-cannot-change-default-datadir-on-debian-9-1-server

Comment: Did you install as `root`?

Answer (score 1):

Services started by Systemd have additional filesystem restrictions imposed by systemd.

It should be possible to provide values to systemd [Service] directives ProtectHome= and/or ProtectSystem= and/or ReadWritePaths= to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

I have similar problem:

When I start the mysql services a message is shown:

Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

if I change the datadir from /etc/mysql/my.cnf again as default; np